# MySQL: Finding servers from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have a table `table1` `a_id` as `PK`,  `ipaddress`, `create_dt`
Here `ipaddress` is `varchar`, `create_dt` is `datetime`

```
a_id    ip              create_dt
9205    10.10.10.10     2017-01-07 08:03:32
9206    10.10.10.11     2017-01-06 08:03:32
9207    10.10.10.12     2015-01-07 08:03:32
```

---more than 1000 rows

I have another mysql table with following columns `id` as `PK`, `ip`, `check_type` `check_status`, `a_id`:
Here `a_id` is foreign key from `table1`

```
id      ip             check_type    check_status  a_id
1       10.10.10.10    check1        FAIL          9205
2       10.10.10.10    check2        PASS          9205
3       10.10.10.11    check1        PASS          9206
4       10.10.10.11    check2        PASS          9206
```

I want all rows from `table1` where `date(create_dt) >= '2017-01-07'` and
`table1.a_id = table2.a_id` and `table2.check1 = 'FAIL'`

So from the above example, my query should return

```
a_id    ip              create_dt
9205    10.10.10.10     2017-01-07 08:03:32
```

I have written the following query and want to know if there is some better way to write the query.
The below query seems to be little slower

```
SELECT *  
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b
  ON a.a_id = b.a_id
WHERE date(a.create_dt) >= '2017-01-07'
AND
b.check_status = 'FAIL'
AND b.check_type = 'check1'
```

Comment: This is how I would write the query, and it should be reasonably fast if tuned with proper indices.

Comment: You can apply your where clause with the inner join itself like a.a_id = b.a_id and b.check_status = 'FAIL' AND b.check_type = 'check1'

Comment: @Mittal can you show it this can be done?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem with the query you already have?

Comment: The query seems to be little slower. I have edited my question with the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the fact you are using an inner join you could assign the condition in where directly in th on clause

```
SELECT *  
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b
  ON a.a_id = b.a_id
    AND date(a.create_dt) >= '2017-01-07'
    AND b.check_status = 'FAIL'
    AND b.check_type = 'check1'
```

The result is the same  .. is just a different way for the jon condition  expression

Answer (score 2):

> I have written the following query and want to know if there is some
>   better way to write the query

Your query looks good. You joined two tables with particular key and apply the where clauses you desired. So, my suggestion would be that don't cast the date like `date(a.create_dt)`. Convert `create_dt` column to `date` field instead.  Applying casting might cause reducing query performance. Whenever possible try to avoid this kind of castings.